# Wilson's Theorem Problem

Tags: congruences

How can we proof that if $p$ is prime and $k$ is integer number that $1<k<p-1$ 
then $(p-k)!(k-1)! \equiv (-1)^k\pmod p$

Comment: @Andrew it's not a duplicate, he's clearly asking a completely different, although *related* question to the one you linked. Consider actually reading the question before you start telling the OP that he needs to look better and linking non-duplicate questions.

Comment: thank you very much for everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We see that (everything being $\mod p$)
\begin{align}
(p-k)!(k-1)!&\equiv(k-1)\cdot(k-2)\cdots2\cdot1\\
&\equiv(p-k)!(-1)^{k-1} (1-k)\cdot(2-k)\cdots-2\cdot-1\\
&\equiv(p-k)!(-1)^{k-1} (p-k+1)\cdot(p-k+2)\cdots(p-2)(p-1)\\
&\equiv(p-1)!(-1)^{k-1}\\
&\equiv(-1)(-1)^{k-1}\\
&\equiv(-1)^k\mod p
\end{align}

Where we use Wilsons theorem at the second-last line, $(p-1)!\equiv -1\mod p$.